# SWR: word for a regulation that relaxes something

Tags: single-word-requests

The sentence is:

> This implies there might be a certain degree of __________ for
>   outbound flows.

I want to say "relaxation" but that sounds to evocative of sitting on the sofa watching tv kind of relaxation. Is there a better choice that has a similar meaning as relaxation but is implying a regulatory context?

Comment: What is needed is more in the way of context.  The most appropriate word might, for all we know BE 'relaxation'.  It is a perfectly normal word to express, for example, the reduction of restrictions.  So we need is of what the flows might be relaxed, please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Leeway.** [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/leeway):

> 2 : an allowable margin of freedom or variation : tolerance
>
> *The new rules allow managers greater **leeway** in making decisions.*

Leeway expresses the discretion a worker has, especially in the face of procedures, policies, or regulations.

Hence:

> This implies there might be a certain degree of **leeway** for outbound flows.

Comment: ...and synonyms: slack, freedom, latitude, looseness, leniency.